# RxJs: updating values in a list from an other stream identified by an ID

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I have two RX infinite streams (let's call them `mainValues` and `decoratorValues`). The one called `mainValues` are adding elements to a list called `valueList`. The other stream (`decoratorValues`) should assign properties to these elements in the list.

**Elements in the two streams are arriving at random times in random order**, and I need to solve it in either order that `mainValues` are **put into the list as soon as available**, while `decoratorValues` **are not lost** until their corresponding elements (identified by an ID) arrive.

```
const mainValues = [ { id: 1, someValue: 'a' }, { id: 2, someValue: 'b'  }, { id: 3, someValue: 'c' }];
const decoratorValues = [ { id: 3, decoratedValue: true }, { id: 2, decoratedValue: false }];

// delay here is only for demonstration purpose 
// a time independent solution can be tested with swapping it between these two
const mainValueStream = Rx.Observable.fromArray(mainValues).delay(2000);
const decoratorStream = Rx.Observable.fromArray(decoratorValues);

const valueList = [];

mainValueStream.subscribe(
  val => valueList.push(val), 
  (err) => console.log(err),
  () => console.log('complete', valueList));

// CODE time independent merging of the two streams go here

// resulting valueList should be:  [ { id: 1, someValue: 'a' }, { id: 2, someValue: 'b', decoratedValue: false }, { id: 3, someValue: 'c', decoratedValue: true } ]
```

### Solution idea

```
mainValueStream
  .concatMap(main => {
     decoratorStream
       .filter(dec => dec.id === main.id)
       .do(dec => {
          main.decoratedValue = dec.decoratedValue;
     }).subscribe(x => x);

     return [main];
  })
  .subscribe(
    val => valueList.push(val), 
    (err) => console.log(err),
    () => console.log('complete', valueList));
```

Unfortunately this only works when all of the decorator values has arrived *before* the main value stream.

My second idea would be adding a second stream that checks if the given value is already in `valueList` and updates it, if it has the element with the appropriate ID.

**Is there a time-independent solution that results in only one stream? Or maybe I'm stuck because I want to solve it with one stream?**

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the best option is `forkJoin()` here. I was thinking about using `zip()` but since you don't have the same order and number of items in each list you'll probably have to wait until both complete and then work with their results.

```
const mainValues = [ { id: 1, someValue: 'a' }, { id: 2, someValue: 'b'  }, { id: 3, someValue: 'c' }];
const decoratorValues = [ { id: 3, decoratedValue: true }, { id: 2, decoratedValue: false }];

// delay here is only for demonstration purpose
// a time independent solution can be tested with swapping it between these two
const mainValueStream = Rx.Observable.from(mainValues).delay(500).toArray();
const decoratorStream = Rx.Observable.from(decoratorValues).toArray();

Observable.forkJoin(mainValueStream, decoratorStream, (main, decorator) => {
    main.forEach(m => {
      decorator.forEach(d => {
        if (m.id === d.id) {
          Object.assign(m, d);
        }
      })
    });

    return main;
  })
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

I'm using two nested `forEach()`s within `forkJoin()`'s result selector function because it seems like the easies way (note that `Object.assign` exists since ES6). I could split it into two Observable streams then filter and merge them but that would get very messy.

This prints to console:

```
[ { id: 1, someValue: 'a' },
  { id: 2, someValue: 'b', decoratedValue: false },
  { id: 3, someValue: 'c', decoratedValue: true } ]
```

EDIT:

If you need everything to be asynchronous than you can use `scan()` to collect decorators as they arrive:

```
const mainValueStream = Rx.Observable.from(mainValues)
  .concatMap(val => Observable.of(val).delay(Math.random() * 1000));

const decoratorStream = Rx.Observable.from(decoratorValues)
  .concatMap(val => Observable.of(val).delay(Math.random() * 1000))
  .scan((acc, val) => {
    acc.push(val);
    return acc;
  }, [])
  .share();


mainValueStream
  .mergeMap(main => decoratorStream
    .mergeAll()
    .filter(d => d.id === main.id)
    .defaultIfEmpty(null)
    .map(d => {
      if (d) {
        return Object.assign(main, d);
      } else {
        return main;
      }
    })
    .take(1)
  )
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

This prints results in random order as they arrive:

```
{ id: 2, someValue: 'b', decoratedValue: false }
{ id: 1, someValue: 'a' }
{ id: 3, someValue: 'c', decoratedValue: true }
```

The core is collection items from `decoratorStream` as they arrive. Then on each item from `mainValueStream` I make another Observable that doesn't emit until it receives its matching decorate item.

Downside of this is that the accumulator in `scan()` is still growing and there's no easy way I can release already used items.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your solution has the problem that items appear only after both streams started. While in the requirements items coming from mainValues must be put into the list (see `const valueList = [];`) as soon as they arrive. I'll update the question to make it extra clear.

Comment: Fortunately the elements of decorator stream are simple records, they do not hold resource expensive values. Also they are not super often (I would say should be estimated a lot below 1000/browsing session). I need some time evaluating the answer, but looks like a solid candidate! Thanks!