# Having one observable mapping to data in a second observable emitting a 3rd observable with data that maps

Tags: typescript, rxjs

The question might be simple for a pro. Having tried multiple ways i couldn'd wrap my head around that.

I have one observable `observable1` containing a list of keys. Like

```
[
 key1,
 key3,
 key4,
 ..
]
```

The second observable `observable2` contains data, some keys of `observable1` map to. Like

```
[
 {key1, val1},
 {key2, val2},
 {key3, val3},
 {key4, val4},
 ..
]
```

For the sake of simplicity let's say every key in `observable1` has a corresponding mapping in `observable2`.

Having this inital situation, i want to have an observable `observable3` only emitting data from `observable2` that is mapped to by a key in `observable1`.

At the given example, the output should omit the data for key2 and look like

```
[
 {key1, val1},
 {key3, val3},
 {key4, val4},
 ..
]
```

after beeing subscribed to and consolelogged.

How can this be archieved in rxjs? By the way, i'm using typescript.

Comment: "i want to have an observable `observable3` only emitting data from `observable2` that is mapped to by a key in `observable1`" - This is under-specified. Remember that observables are infinite, time-dependent streams of events. The key you're looking for could arrive on the stream a moment later, or you could wait for ever for the event to arrive. Do you mean to search only the keys that have _previously_ been observed on `observable1`?

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but the data of `observable1` and `observable2` must be already there when requesting data from the 3rd observable with a `.subscribe`.

Comment: No. Observables are (possibly) infinite, time-dependent streams of events. Events can happen in the past or the future. An observable can broadcast an event based on, eg, a user pressing a button or a message arriving on a websocket. For the most part, calls to `subscribe` will happen at startup time, before most events have fired.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Since OP's using RxJS I'm 99.9% sure this is not what he's dealing with :).

Answer (score 0):

As I outlined in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42378939/having-one-observable-mapping-to-data-in-a-second-observable-emitting-a-3rd-obse?noredirect=1#comment71907382_42378939), what you describe isn't possible. Observables are (possibly) infinite, real-time streams of events. The events in an observable may come from, eg, a user pressing a button, or a message on a websocket. When an event arrives on `observable2`, you haven't necessarily received all of the events from `observable1`, so you don't know whether or not its key will be in the stream.

What *is* possible is asking whether an object's key is present in the set of keys that have *previously been received* on `observable1` at a given point in time. The nice, purely functional way of doing this would involve aggregating `observable1` into a [`Behavior`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive-banana-1.1.0.1/docs/Reactive-Banana-Combinators.html#t:Behavior) containing a set of keys using [`accumB`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive-banana-1.1.0.1/docs/Reactive-Banana-Combinators.html#v:accumB) and then [`filter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive-banana-1.1.0.1/docs/Reactive-Banana-Combinators.html#v:filterE)ing `observable2` based on the current value of that `Behavior`. Problem is, the `Behavior` type is conspicuously absent from the RxJS API. (This is why the Reactive Extensions ecosystem kinda sucks in my opinion: by breaking the continuous-time model you lose a lot of the composability of FRP.)

So we're forced to break the FRP abstraction and use a mutable variable to hold the keys that we've previously seen at a given moment in time. Then [`filter`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/filter.html) `observable2` by looking at the set of keys in this variable.

```
type KeyValuePair<K, V> = { key: K, val: V };

function filterByKey<K, V>(
    keys: Observable<K>,
    o: Observable<KeyValuePair<K, V>>
): Observable<KeyValuePair<K, V>> {
    // IRL I'd build some sort of Set abstraction
    // (on top of the keys of an object) to ensure
    // that this scales up to big sets of keys
    var seenKeys: K[] = [];

    keys.subscribe(key => {
        if (seenKeys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
            seenKeys.push(key);
        }
    });

    return o.filter(x => seenKeys.indexOf(x.key) !== -1);
}
```

(I'm coding without an editor, so I might have got that a bit wrong, but that's the idea.)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure I interpreted what you want correctly, but looking at the output you could do something like this:

```
const observable1 = Rx.Observable.fromArray(['key1','key3', 'key4'])
const observable2 = Rx.Observable.fromArray([
  {key1: 'val1'},
  {key2: 'val2'},
  {key3: 'val3'},
  {key4: 'val4'}
])

const observable3 = observable1
  .flatMap(key => observable2.skipWhile(obj => !obj.hasOwnProperty(key)).take(1))
```

The output starts mapping `observable1`, taking each key and skipping everything in `observable2` until that key is found. Then emitting a single element. Mind that if the order of the keys are mixed, **this won't work** - and I don't think it's possible without storing the objects in a more persistent way.

If these objects are not coming in async, as a stream, but are rather in a simple data structure that are available from the start, using `Observables` might not benefit you. If you have all the data from the start, then you could do something like this:

```
const keys = ['key1','key3', 'key4']
const objects = [
  {key1: 'val1'},
  {key2: 'val2'},
  {key3: 'val3'},
  {key4: 'val4'}
]

const output = objects.filter(obj => keys.includes(Object.keys(obj)[0]))
```

Comment: This `skipWhile`&`take` is a nice solution, unfortunately i can't make an assumption about the order of the keys.

Comment: This won't work due to the point I made in [my comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42378939/having-one-observable-mapping-to-data-in-a-second-observable-emitting-a-3rd-obse?noredirect=1#comment71907382_42378939). It happens to work for this test case because you're using `fromArray`; you have all your data upfront and your observables are already completed (ie you are not really using them as observables).

Answer (score -1):

This is very similar to a question from yesterday: [RxJs: updating values in a list from an other stream identified by an ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42349778/rxjs-updating-values-in-a-list-from-an-other-stream-identified-by-an-id/42370161#42370161)

Since the number of items and order can't be guaranteed you can most easily collect all items from both `observable1` and `observable2` and then merge them into one Observable:

```
let observable1 = Observable.from(['key1', 'key3', 'key4']);
let observable2 = Observable.from([{id: 'key1', val: 'val1'}, {id: 'key2', val: 'val2'}, {id: 'key3', val: 'val3'}, {id: 'key4', val: 'val4'}]);

let observable3 = Observable.forkJoin(
  observable1.toArray(),
  observable2.toArray(),
  (keys1, results1) => {
    let results = [];
    keys1.forEach(key => {
      results1.forEach(result => {
        if (key === result.id) {
          results.push(result);
        }
      });
    });

    return results;
  });

observable3
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

The biggest disadvantage is that you have to collect all items from both Observables before merging them.

This prints to console:

```
[ { id: 'key1', val: 'val1' },
  { id: 'key3', val: 'val3' },
  { id: 'key4', val: 'val4' } ]
```